# What do you call a medicine that takes signicantly more time after intake to be effective?

Tags: word-request

I was thinking of "late onset medicine", but I am not sure if this is the term that would be used, and I am wondering if there are any other term that may be more correct or appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One phrase is "slow-acting" as given by the [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/slow-acting).

> **slow-acting** (in British)
>   adjective
>
> **working or acting slowly, not immediately**
>
> *a slow-acting toxin/drug/poison*

Comment: Some drugs are also described as **slow release** - although this is not the same as a retarded effect